# PowerShell - Dynamic variable names in workflow

Tags: powershell, variables, dynamic, parallel-processing, workflow

Is it possible to create dynamic variable names in a PowerShell workflow?

I want some piece of code where the content of some files is put together in one variable.

I know this is quite simple like this:

```
ForEach ($file in $files) { 
    $list = Get-content $srcdirectory\$file
    $longlist = $longlist + $list
}
```

This way the content of one file is put inside `$list` and then in `$longlist`. It then starts with the next file, puts that content in `$list`, and adds that to `$longlist` (The old content in `$list` is **overwritten** by the new content, but the new content will be **added** to `$longlist`, after the old content).

But I want to do this in parallel, so each file is read at the same time to increase speed.
So my idea was to create a `workflow` (necessary for `Foreach -Parallel`), put a `ForEach -Parallel` loop in it, and use for each file (and thus for each 'thread') a different variable to combine these variables later on in the script.
I tried this:

```
workflow workflow1 {
    ForEach -Parallel ($file in $files) { 
        $list = Get-content $file
        New-Variable -Name "var$file" -Value $list
    }
}
```

But since this is 'not suited for workflows' will it not work this way.
How can I achieve this anyway?

NOTE: I already tried to achieve this using jobs, but that was about 10 times slower than file after file, which is not wat I want. I want it to be faster than file after file.
I also read something about runspaces, but I can't really find a good explanation or tutorial about that.

Comment: Here is an awesome implementation of runspaces, easy to use and with examples: Invoke-Parallel: https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/Invoke-Parallel

Comment: [I think the easiest way to use runspaces by far is using the PoshRsJob module by Boe Prox](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob). It lets you use them with basically the same semantics as jobs.

Comment: What kind of computer do you have where single threaded CPU performance is the limiting factor in reading from files, and not disk IO? Every time you do `$longlist = $longlist + $list` powershell creates a new, bigger array and copies longlist into it. It's famously, dreadfully slow to do in a loop, and if you change longlist for a `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` and use `$Longlist.Add($list)` you will probably see performance improvement.

Comment: Same with Get-Content which is slow because it has lots of options and works with other PSProviders not just filesystems; You might get performance improvement by changing that for `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines()`

Comment: [This article](https://mjolinor.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/invoke-scritptasync-v2/) should get you working with Runspaces in no time, its what I discovered and haven't looked back.